# Difference with /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python3

Tags: python

My question is, what is the difference between /usr/bin/python3.6 and /usr/bin/python3.
I am using cronjob for running python script. Script is not running under python 3.4 but it is running under 3.6 version. 
However whenever I am changing it to /usr/bin/python3 it is also running.

What should I use then in cronjob, exact version like 3.6 or just 3?
What is best practice?
Thanks.

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3` could be a symbolic link of your highiest Python version. So maybe it's `/usr/bin/python3.6`

Comment: We don't know what exactly the difference is *on your system.* Use `.../python3 -V` etc. to see each executable's version. See `ls -l /usr/bin/python*` to see if any is a symlink to another.

Comment: /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6 got it) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin/python3` is the platform default Python 3 installation. It's often inadvisable to change it because of dependencies that other parts of the system may have on it, so it's often older than the latest release. It's normally a symlink to a specific version, so if you want to know what version it actually is run:

```
ls -al /usr/bin/python3
```

If you write scripts that need a later language or library versions than `/usr/bin/python3` then you will need to install and specify a specific version to ensure you pick those up.

Much beyond that I doubt it matters too much; most distros backport security fixes to their default Python installation so the only reason to use a newer version is a desire to use the new features.

Comment: Thanks for reply. ls -al /usr/bin/python3 command gave  /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6 which is default version is 3.4. I got it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no best or worst practice. It's a different python version. Use whichever works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the New Topics of python3.6 [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep525)

Well for your query python3.6 has backward compatibility will all versions lower than 3.6

Here is reference example relaed to literal

```
# python 3.7.4
>> platform="stackoverflow"
>> print(f"we are on {platform}")
we are on stackoverflow

# python 3.4.3
>> platform="stackoverflow"
>> print(f"we are on {platform}")
  File "main.py", line 1                                                                    
    print(f"we are on {platform}")                                                     
                                ^                                                      
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I hope this clarify your doubt

Comment: Thanks for clarification. With new version new features are coming and not compatible with previous versions. Thanks for reply.